Не сжимает картинки всех форматов кроме webp Gulp imagemin
проблема такая: при использовании сборки GULP плагин webp / imagamin делают вот такие странные вещи. Картинки в папке dist/img создаются, формат webp переводится и работает хорошо, а вот jpg картинка не открывается(пишет: формат файла не поддерживается). Менял местами .pipe ошибка становится актуальной на webp разширениях, а jpg работают.
import webp from 'gulp-webp'
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin'

export const images = () => {
  return app.gulp
    .src(app.path.src.images, { encoding: false })
    .pipe(
      app.plugins.plumber(
        app.plugins.notify.onError({
          title: 'IMAGES',
          message: 'Error: <%= error.message %>',
        }),
      ),
    )
    .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(webp())
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.src.images))
    .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(
      imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
        interlaced: true,
        optimizationLevel: 3,
      }),
    )
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.src.svg))
    .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
    .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream())
}


У Вас похоже все будет webp, и работаете Вы скорее всего на Windows (потому что там расширение играет роль)

Как будто формат webp переводится и работает хорошо, а вот jpg картинка не открывается  и ошибка становится актуальной на webp разширениях, а jpg работают противоречие.

Везде, где встречается app.gulp.src() - добавьте параметр { encoding: false }
